# Nodejs and Socket.io https issue (socket.io polling continuously)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

i have set up a node js server and socket.io with redis. 
If im creating a http server everything works fine, but i switched to https requests and socket.io has a problem with polling. It does continuously polling and i dont get it why...(via http it does not polling continuously)

see here (it counts up to 10000+): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH2aV.png

I have this problem only if i use https...and i dont get it why he is doing that.

Here is my server.js

```
var app     = require('express')();
var https   = require('https');
var fs      = require('fs');
var io      = require('socket.io')(https);
var redis   = require('redis');



var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('xxxxxx'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('xxxxxx')
};

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {

res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.at");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
         res.statusCode = 200;
  res.end("hello world\n");
  console.log("hi");
}).listen(3389, 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx');



io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  console.log("new client connected");
  var redisClient = redis.createClient();
  redisClient.subscribe('message');


  redisClient.on("message", function(channel, notification) {
    console.log("mew notifications in queue "+ notification + "channel");
    socket.emit(channel, notification);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    redisClient.quit();
  });
  socket.on('reconnecting', function() {
    console.log("adsasd");
  });
});
```

And here is my client code:

```
var socket = io.connect('<?php echo env('SOCKET_CONNECT_URL'); ?>', {secure: true});

        socket.on('message', function (data) {
            handleNotifications(data);
            updateNotifications();
        });
```

So my question is, why is socket.io polling continuously and what is wrong with my code or do i unterstand something wrong?

Ps.: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What does the PHP `echo env('SOCKET_CONNECT_URL')` evaluate to?  In other words, what is actually being sent to `io.connect()` in the client?

Comment: Hi, the echo env('SOCKET_CONNECT_URL')`  return the Socket URL its the same as `listen(3389, 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx');`

What you mean by seing sent to the client? The Response of the polling url is just hello world.

In my CLI the console.log("hi"); is fired 10000+ times too.

Comment: Did you figured out solution for this issue?

Comment: I am also getting same issues since yesterday. Did you figured out solution for this issue @rkan07.